# Higher dimension space of the real number

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

This is maybe an easy question but I really have a problem with understanding that in higher dimensions.

I want to know for $\mathbb{R}^n$ what does the subset $B=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x_n=0\}$ represents where $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)^T$.

For $n=1$, $B$ consists of a point, namely, $B=\{0\}$. For $n=2$, $B=\mathbb{R}$ which is the real line, $n=3$, I have $B=\mathbb{R}^2$ which is the plane. When $n=4$, I will have $B=\mathbb{R}^3$, is this a surface or a higher plane? Also, when we have higher dimesnion, is the a specific name for $B$?

With the best regards for all.

Comment: Any set of the form $a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n=c$ is called a *hyperplane* in $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to see this. Firstly, we know that $B_n$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with dimension $n-1$. So yes, $B_3$ is indeed a plane. Usually referred to as a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$. How does that plane look like? Well, if $x\in B_n$, then $x$ is orthogonal to $e_n = (0,0,..., 1)$. So it is a very specific hyperplane. Hope this helps.